# How do I prepend first element of Observable<T> to each group?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I've got `Observable<String> playerNames` where the 1st element is a header. How do I break down it into multiple chunks (while prepending a header to each group)?

```
playerNamesObservable
     .window(100)
     .to(chunk -> { return playerNamesObservable.concatWith(chunk) }
```

where `headerObservable` is basically `playerNamesObservable.first()`

The problem is that I want to be really careful about emitting items (don't want to use `blockingGet`, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `publish`:

```
recordsObservable.publish(shared -> {
    Observable<String> first = shared
        .take(1)
        .replay()
        .autoConnect(0);

    return shared.skip(1)
        .window(100)
        .map(w -> w.startWith(first));
})
.flatMap(chunk -> /* consume each chunk */)
```

Comment: Could you explain why do we need `autoConnect(0)`? I read about .replay() and I believe it should work without `autoConnect(0)`.

Comment: You need to establish a connection to the first element manually because the `startWith` inside the `map` would execute too late and the very first element would have got lost by the time.

Comment: Can I replace .replay().autoConnect(0) with a simple .cache()?

Comment: No, you have to trigger the subscription on that path to the shared `Observable`.

Comment: Hi again, your solution doesn't work when recordsObservable.count() == 1. Is there any opportunity to fix it?

Comment: How does it not work? You should get the header and not further data.

Comment: Yep, I added `.doOnNext()` before and after `.publish()` and here're the results (basically we print 'before' for every record we pass (header's a record, too; we've got 5 headers there -> we should have received 5 'after', but in fact there're only 2 for the ones with some content except header):
[DEBUG]: before: 
[DEBUG]: before: 
[DEBUG]: before: 
[DEBUG]: before: 
[DEBUG]: before: 
[DEBUG]: before: 
[DEBUG]: before: 
[DEBUG]: after: 
[DEBUG]: after: 
[DEBUG]: before:

Comment: Basically .window() doesn't emit anything for empty observable.

Comment: You should get a new window after every 100 source items. If you have only 50 items, you'll get one window.

Comment: If the source is completely empty, there is no header to emit and no window to emit to. Why do you need an empty inner window? If you really need one, use a completed `PublishSubject` with `switchIfEmpty` for example.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I need a function that kinda similar to window but emits the remainder, too.